# In Stata, how do I test for interaction of categorical variables in multilevel models?

Tags: categorical-data, stata, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to figure out a way to test for interaction between variables in three level model. Using example Stat dataset we can have a dummy model with states nested into regions:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/productivity

xtile unemp_q = unemp, nq(5)
xtile private_q = private, nq(5)
xtile emp_q = emp, nq(5)

mixed gsp i.private_q i.unemp_q i.emp_q || region: || state:
est sto m1
```

Now, using the logic of working with non-hierarchical data in OLS or cox regression I'd do:

```
mixed gsp i.private_q##i.unemp_q i.emp_q || region: || state:
est sto m2

testparm i.private_q#i.unemp_q
lrtest m1 m2
```

Both test give a p < 0.002.

```
. testparm i.private_q#i.unemp_q

 ( 1)  [gsp]2.private_q#2.unemp_q = 0
... (omitted)
 (16)  [gsp]5.private_q#5.unemp_q = 0

           chi2( 16) =   38.41
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0013

. lrtest m1 m2

Likelihood-ratio test                                 LR chi2(16) =     37.41
(Assumption: m1 nested in m2)                         Prob > chi2 =    0.0018
```

Would that indicate no interaction between variables `unemp_q` and `private_q`? Is there any better way to solve that?